# Node.js callbacks; how to join SerialPort subsequent data events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a problem with SerialPort in Node.js that I can't resolve. In MODBUS RTU protocol, a message is considered fully transmitted if a specified timeout (let's say, 10 ms) occurs between two data chunks.
My experience with SerialPort shows that I often get e.g. one or a few bytes in a single data event, when the actual message could be as long as 100 bytes. Now, how do I know if message has ended and I can pass data to further handlers? Well, now I do the following:

```
var timeoutTimer;
function dataEventHandler(chunk) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutTimer);
    // concatenate the chunks
    timeoutTimer = setTimeout(10, handleFullMessage);
}
```

which obviously is not the best approach... just imagine another callback chimes in, e.g. HTTP request handler, which could evaluate up to 100 ms long.

Several ideas:

- in `handleFullMessage()` check if there is something available on serial port, and if so, just exit, assuming a data event may be called again (MODBUS is a master/slave protocol, so no one will talk without a request). But I don't know how to do it.
- somehow prioritize data events over timeouts...

Comment: Don't the serialport events have timestamps?

Comment: I can safely assume that if the data event occurs, it is a part of current message (slave will not speak not having been commanded earlier); therefore I don't even need the timestamp. But this does not solve my problem, as I still have to pass my message after a certain amount of time. Let me give an example:
1. dataEventHandler is called. handleFullMessage is scheduled to be called in 10 ms.
2. a 100 ms operation is executing (e.g. HTTP handler)
3. in the meantime serial data arrived and another 'data' event is added to the callback queue, but...
4. unfortunately handleFullMessage is called.

Comment: No, I meant the events themselves not the message. So that in the handler you check when the event occured (in contrast to, when the handler does execute).

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure how exactly the Node.js event queue is implemented, but I would expect that if the data arrives before the 10ms timeout, then the `dataEventHandler` call for it would be scheduled before the `handleFullMessage` as well. Even if both are deferred by 100ms by an ongoing task.

Comment: Have you looked at the [available MODBUS modules](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=modbus)?

Comment: Yes, I'm actually developing one (jsModbus). No other meets my needs (RTU RS-485 stack)

Comment: Well, I guess I'll look at the ordering of events in event loop queue again, maybe @Bergi is right about it :)